# How to execute a function to update the values of dynamically created inputs after entire page has been loaded and rendered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using datatables to dynamically create input fields. Each input field has a unique ID.
I need to run a function once the entire page has been loaded and all elements have been rendered.
The function should update the values of all the dynamically created inputs.
Using document.onload does not seem to work. It works sometimes and sometimes doesn't.

I have tried using document.onload. It works like 20% of the time. I can't seem to understand why. document.onload should call the function after document.ready has been fully executed. But the values of dynamically created inputs don't change.

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
  refresh_all_equity_credit_values();
});
```

```
$('#dynamic_input_id').val('2'); // Does not work
```

The values of dynmically created inputs should be updated once the entire page has been loaded and all elements has been rendered.

Comment: The window is loading before data tables is done doing it's thing, it dosnt care about whatever asynchronous actions things on the page are doing. You will need a different trigger, something within datatables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the datatables library, you'll likely want to wait until you're certain it has finished rendering the inputs before you attempt to update them. Check out their [documentation on available events](https://datatables.net/reference/event/)

You'll likely want to use the `draw` event:

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('#yourDataTable').on('draw', function() {
    refresh_all_equity_credit_values()
  })
})
```